# Customize Identity default UI In asp.net with react

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, entity-framework, identityserver4

I am working on asp.net 5.0.12 with react and had selected identity individual on creating project it created a new project with user authentication but I want when login to select a branch and when register select multiple branches

so I want to customize the default UI and add input as roles
but the code for the UI, I cannot find it and tried searching and a add new scaffolding to add identity

It create a Area fold with all the forms in razor format and when I go run it gives error of

**`InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").`**

tried searching that error they say add @RenderSection something but not working

when I Created the scaffolding Got a link to doc that says do some steps not work

```
Support for ASP.NET Core Identity was added to your project.

For setup and configuration information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2116645.
```

I Am getting this error Full

```
    An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
```

that was for stack
for **query**

```
Variable    Value
ReturnUrl   /connect/authorize/callback?client_id=AmruthERP&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44332%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=AmruthERPAPI%20openid%20profile&state=d4142fba4a73429386dbcbe95c945687&code_challenge=mzfC0GFfeb-wy-a0vOdS4vAkHX_6eWHtu8sqkXn3RwA&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query
```

**Headers**

```
Variable    Value
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection  close
Host    localhost:44332
Referer https://localhost:44332/authentication/login?returnUrl=https://localhost:44332/
sec-ch-ua   "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile    ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform  "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest  document
sec-fetch-mode  navigate
sec-fetch-site  same-origin
upgrade-insecure-requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
```

**Routing**

```
Endpoint
Name    Value
Display Name    /Account/Login
Route Pattern   Identity/Account/Login
Route Order 0
Route Values
Variable    Value
area    Identity
page    /Account/Login
```

Please help stuck for 3 days

or can suggest a link which they have added roles in asp.net with react indentity

Comment: tried scaffolding in angular project just to test and it work check in angular but react what is the issue